# Embed Code for Olympics

Tags: embed

I am not sure if this is technically the right place to ask but here it goes:

I would like to have on my site a medal count for the upcoming 2012 Olympics. My question is this:

Is there a simple embed code that could do this?

OR

How to I create one?

Thanks for the assistance and help.

Comment: Other than tracking the Olympics yourself, it would be unlikely that there is an API that does it for you.

Comment: @Christopher I just answered her question

Comment: @Anagio, very nice find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do people down vote this? I gave you +1 and here is the answer

http://www.nbcolympics.com/widgets/index.html

- Super Widget (Top News, Video and Slideshows)
- Team USA Tracker
- Medal Tracker
- Watch Widget

Comment: @Lynda You're very welcome